How to search a short list a large number of times?
I have to search a small list (varies from 0 to 10 items) a large number of times and was wondering what the best way to do that would be using Python (specifically IronPython 2.7)
The number of search runs will always be many times more than the number of items in the list to search. For example, if the list to search has 5 items in it, I will likely have to search that list 50 or more times. Search runs will not be sequential. In other words, I have a function that does a bunch of stuff on an object with the search being a part of that. The function is called repeatedly with different objects.
The number of matches for any given search is likely to be zero but could easily be more than one. And I need all matches. The function calling the search does not use the results; rather it is a different function processing other types of objects that will use the results.
I have this data structure:
  MyDataClass:
    ListToSearch ( (AcadEntID, Pt1, Pt2) (AcadEntID Pt1, Pt2) ...)
    Results { AcadEntID : ( (RevitLineID,  EndPtInx) (RevitLineID,  EndPtInx) ...),
                            (RevitLineID,  EndPtInx) (RevitLineID,  EndPtInx) ...))
              AcadEntID : ( (RevitLineID,  EndPtInx) (RevitLineID,  EndPtInx) ...),
                            (RevitLineID,  EndPtInx) (RevitLineID,  EndPtInx) ...))

            }

The input for each will be the RevitLineID (from which an endpoints can be taken: PtA and PtB)
The test asks this: For each AcadEntID, is PtA within a box centered on Pt1? Or is it within a box centered on Pt2? Repeat for PtB. Each point has an X and Y value.
If it is more efficient, ListToSearch could be broken up into multiple pieces so long as each point remains associated with AcadEntID.
This program is being developed in RevitPythonShell but will eventually be part of a PyRevit addin.
So there it is. I need a very quick way to search a short list a large number of times.

Is there some other requirement that forces you to use a list? It seems like the ideal situation to convert the list into a tree, which would greatly optimise search speeds.

Not that I know of. I am assuming you are talking about the ListToSearch part of things. Does Python support trees?

if the list is short, it probably doesn't matter how you do it unless you're doing these searches millions of times.

@Michelle , numerous trees out there in python world .... treelib, bigtree ...

Can you put some numbers to "small" and "large number of times"? How small? And what do you consider a large number of times, or rather, what is the search frequency?

Hmmm...An Autocad dwg might contain anywhere from 100 entities to 1000 entities depending on the detail being drawn. Of those, 30% to 90% will be line entities and anywhere from 0 to 10 entities could be dimensions. I need to check the two points of each line against the confines of a box centered on each of 2 pts in each dimension. So a test of 1800 x-values against 40 x-values and 1800 y-values against 40 y-values

If there are no duplicate entries in your list, a set may be more appropriate

For quick and efficient searching, a Python dictionary is the collection of choice. You need to implement the dictionary so that its search key corresponds to whatever you are searching for. Where does the list originate? If you created it yourself, just create a dictionary instead right from the start. Otherwise, you can easily convert a list to a dictionary.

Unfortunately, I do not think a dictionary would work as I am not looking for an exact match to a value but rather items that fall between a range of values. And each item has four values (two points) that must be checked against two values (a point) to see if it is a valid match. Best I have come up with so far is 4 sorted lists that I perform a binary search on. I can post some code as answer if that would be of use.

You can implement a comparison operator that takes all of your comparison requirements into account, including multiple values to compare and a fuzziness to equate values that are not exactly equal, only more or less similar, and define exactly how much fuzziness is required.
